# How do I verify that compiler options have been set correctly in msvc 2010 c++ project at compile time?

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-options

I have been playing around with PDCurses and have been having a few problems.   Eventually I landed [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/pdcurses/discussion/95731/thread/f3564621/?limit=25#837) which had a solution to my problem.

Basically my PDCurses project was compiled with the UNICODE CHARACTER set.  As a result the block character was being displayed as an upper case U.  Setting the library to NOT SET as the character set solved this problem.

**Is there a technique that would allow me to embed something in the source code for PDCurses that would detect which character set option was picked and do a compile time ASSERT if it is not set properly?**

I have looked at the pragma listing.  The conform option and runtime checks seem to do something similar.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no compiler option "Character set". Selecting this switch in Visual Studio generates _UNICODE macro, that can be tested in the program text.

Comment: Test _MBCS (Multi-byte) and _UNICODE macros. If none of them defined, character set is not selected.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work.  Thanks

```
#ifdef _UNICODE
    #error "Unicode may not be set for this library"
#else
    #ifdef _MBCS
        #error "Multi Byte may not be set for this libary"
    #endif
#endif
```